Why does my PayPal sandbox app permissions authorization fails?
I'm getting error
[2024-07-31 10:49:37] INFO: Response from tracking information request: Array
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => NOT_AUTHORIZED
                    [message] => Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions
                    [debug_id] => e5447f683bf65
                    [details] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [location] => body
                                    [links] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)

while trying to create php code to send tracking information to PayPal using their tracking API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/tracking/v1/
I doubled and tripled checked credentials. Do I need to create any kind of permissions for this to work?
